# Revert "vagrant global-status --prune" command

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

probably in my stupidity I used `vagrant global-status --prune` command and delete all my "connections" (does it call **entries**?) between **Vagrant** and my **VirtualBox**.

How can I fix this? Pls halp guys, I can't work without this (ಠ﹏ಥ)

Comment: You might try this tip -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949635/how-can-i-restore-my-vagrant-vm-all-file-have-been-deleted

Answer (score 0):

According to the vagrant documentation: if the environment is not showing up.
run

```
$vagrant destroy
```

then

```
$vagrant up
```